# Integer corruption

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny, data-type

I use a sensor to measure the temperature. This is returned as float. I feed this float using typecasting (int) to a blink function. This works fine.
But the next is step is using this same unchanged integer in a struct and send it over 433MHz using RadioHead.
Here the integer is no longer an integer and it never gets sent.

When I hard code the sensor measurement value, it works. When I hard code the value in the struct it works. When I hard code the value anywhere it works.

My assumption is: when the blink works it must be an integer. When sending a hard coded integer works it must also send the measured value confirmed to be an integer. What am I missing here?

The chip is an ATtiny85
The sensor is a DS18B20
TinyHead, my light RadioHead version: https://gitlab.com/thijsvanulden/TinyHead

This is the Logic Analyzer view of what happens measured on the Data pin of the 433MHz transmitter. So something is happening at least. I can't find an Analyzer 'plugin' to translate the message coded in RadioHead, it's not Manchester encoding as it seems.

[image: logic analyzer]

```
Memory Usage -> http://bit.ly/pio-memory-usage
DATA:    [========  ]  75.8% (used 388 bytes from 512 bytes)
PROGRAM: [========= ]  86.4% (used 7080 bytes from 8192 bytes)
```

---

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define TICKLE_ID 0

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

#define RADIOHEAD_BAUD 2000
#define RADIOHEAD_TX_PIN 1
#define RADIOHEAD_RX_PIN -1

#define LEDPIN 0

struct tickle {
  uint16_t id = TICKLE_ID;
  uint16_t value1;
  uint16_t value2;
};

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
RH_ASK driver(RADIOHEAD_BAUD, RADIOHEAD_RX_PIN, RADIOHEAD_TX_PIN);

void blink(int repeat) {
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
    _delay_ms(100);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    _delay_ms(100);
  }
}

void senddata(float temperatuur) {
  blink((int) temperatuur); // this always works
  struct tickle package; // make a Tickle package
  package.id = TICKLE_ID; // hard-coded device ID
  package.value1 = 0; // any positive int up to 2^16
  package.value2 = temperatuur * 100; // any positive int up to 2^16
  driver.send((uint8_t *)&package, sizeof(package));
  driver.waitPacketSent(); // wait for it ~Barney
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
  sensors.begin();
  driver.init();
  _delay_ms(100);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  _delay_ms(100);
  senddata(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // hard coded 17.07 works
  _delay_ms(10000);
}
```

**Changes made as suggested by @Jot**

```cpp
void senddata(float temperatuur) {
  temperatuur = (uint16_t) temperatuur;
  blink(temperatuur);
  struct tickle package; // make a Tickle package
  package.id = (uint16_t) TICKLE_ID; // hard-coded device ID
  package.value1 = (uint16_t) 0; // any positive int up to 2^16
  package.value2 = (uint16_t) 100; // any positive int up to 2^16

  blink(sizeof(package));
  driver.send((uint8_t *)&package, sizeof(package));
  driver.waitPacketSent(); // wait for it ~Barney
}
```

**Working code, the end result**
You may need to skip the Powernap code, it's a sleep library for ATtiny85. And I use the TinyHead library for 433MHz. The OneWire interaction with the sensors is 'borrowed' from http://www.nerdkits.com/forum/thread/2849/ so please send the beer and kudo's there.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <powernap.h>

#define TICKLE_ID 0
//
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
//
#define RADIOHEAD_BAUD 2000
#define RADIOHEAD_TX_PIN 1
#define RADIOHEAD_RX_PIN -1

#define LEDPIN 0

struct tickle {
  uint16_t id = TICKLE_ID;
  uint16_t value1;
  uint16_t value2;
};

Napper napper;
OneWire TemperatureSensor(2);
RH_ASK driver(RADIOHEAD_BAUD, RADIOHEAD_RX_PIN, RADIOHEAD_TX_PIN);

void blink(int repeat) {
  for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
    napper.delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    napper.delay(100);
  }
}

void senddata(float temperatuur) {
  blink((int) temperatuur);
  struct tickle package; // make a Tickle package
  package.id = TICKLE_ID; // hard-coded device ID
  package.value1 = 0; // any positive int up to 2^16
  package.value2 = temperatuur * 100; // any positive int up to 2^16

  blink(sizeof(package));
  driver.send((uint8_t *)&package, sizeof(package));
  driver.waitPacketSent(); // wait for it ~Barney
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
  driver.init();
  napper.setup();
  napper.delay(100);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  byte i;
  byte data[12];
  int16_t raw;
  float celsius, fahrenheit;

  TemperatureSensor.reset();       // reset one wire buss
  TemperatureSensor.skip();        // select only device
  TemperatureSensor.write(0x44);   // start conversion

  delay(1000);                     // wait for the conversion

  TemperatureSensor.reset();
  TemperatureSensor.skip();
  TemperatureSensor.write(0xBE);   // Read Scratchpad
  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {       // 9 bytes
    data[i] = TemperatureSensor.read();
  }

  // Convert the data to actual temperature
  raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
  celsius = (float)raw / 16.0;
  napper.delay(100);
  senddata(celsius);
  napper.napminutes(1);
}
```

Comment: Which arduino board do you use? The OneWire and DallasTemperature require some memory, but the RadioHead requires a lot of memory.

Comment: @Jot - how is that relevant? if `senddata(17.07);` works as intended, but `senddata(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));` does not?

Comment: what sensor are you using? .... what format is the returned data?

Comment: Is it possible you think you are sending three bytes of data while you might actually be sending six bytes of data.

Comment: @Thijs, still using the attiny85? or is it a secret and you don't you want to tell us which arduino board you use? When you use a non-standard arduino board, then I would like to know which core you use. Perhaps that is a secret as well? There are issues and notes about many problem with the attiny85 and RadioHead. Have you read: "Caution: we have not had good success building RH_ASK sketches for ATTiny 85" on this page: https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/ The RadioHead uses a lot more memory than the old VirtualWire. I would not even recommend the RadioHead for an Arduino Uno.

Comment: What do you mean by “the integer is no longer an integer and it never gets sent”? What makes you believe an integer can be anything but an integer? What are the _exact_ symptoms you observe?

Comment: Yes, I use an ATtiny85. It is the Dallas sensor DS18B20. The returned format is `float`. @Jot sry forgot to mention I use the ATtiny85. I have 17 sensors running with this chip and using TinyHead, my light version of RadioHead, no problems there. VirtualWire does not provide the same functionality and is deprecated for years with the developer referring to RadioHead. 
The exact symptoms are that the RadioHead library does not send out the message. In depth debugging is really hard with an ATtiny85 so can't really tell you more at the moment but I'm open to ideas.
@st2000 please elaborate?

Comment: @st2000 I changed my code so the LED blinks the package size and sizeof(package) returns 6.

Comment: ...yes, this is because your structure is made of 3 uint16_t values.  Then you force the code to consider it as uint8_t values.  Of which there is enough memory set aside for 6 such values.  I was wondering if this was what you were expecting to send?  Or if this was why you do not think you are sending the correct data.

Comment: ...also, as other's here point out, the Arduino paradigm has been ported to many many different processors.  And some of the ports are not 100% functional.  In fact, it can easily be said that not 100% of all Arduino programs run on 100% of all "so called" Arduino platforms.

Comment: Please also add a link in your question to TinyHead. I can't see the problem. Therefor you have to be able to get closer to the problem with other output. Can you add a serial port, a display, or a led? Perhaps you can blink a led 17 times for 17 degrees in the function `senddata` and check if you see any difference for a constant or the ds18b20. By the way, I have stripped down the RadioHead for myself, saving a lot of ram. That makes it possible to use it with an arduino uno. I doubt if the TinyHead for a attiny85 is tiny enough so it can still use the ds18b20 libraries.

Comment: @st2000 where do I force the code to consider it uint8? What would be the alternative?

Comment: @Jot I’ve used an LED to signal the temparature and its read fine. I also used it to signal the package size for the transmission and it’s 6 bytes. I will try to connect my logic analyzer later. Yes is all works with a constant. Thats the problem, it always works with any integer unless the integer comes from the sensor, even when I verify this interger is fine by blinking the LED.

Comment: @Thijs I think I did not read it very well and was rude, my apologies. Can you do a test: fool the compiler to make it think that `getTempCByIndex` is used, but send a constant. In the function `senddata`: convert it: `uint16_t t = temperature;` get rid of it: `t /= 10000;` add a constant: `t += 1789;` fill the package: `package.value2 = t;`. Linking the `getTempCByIndex` function into the binary might be too much for the ram usage.

Comment: @Jot no problem. I've made the changes and nothing is transmitted but I do see the right temperature signaled by the blink function. On the logic analyzer there is a signal again, but I still cant decode it.

Comment: I'll try to use another more light library or write my own oneWire stuff so I can free up some memory.

Comment: Casting values is like telling the compiler "don't mind what these memory locations were, now I want you to treat them differently".  So, you used 6 bytes of memory to store 3 uint16_t values.  Then you told the compiler to look at the 6 bytes of memory as if they were uint8_t values.   You further cemented your intentions by specifying the "size" of the values.  That is, the size of function returned that you had used 6 bytes of memory for the storage of the 3 uint16_t variables or, as you casted them, 6 uint8_t variables.

Comment: @st2000 I still do not know where I tell the compiler to look at the 6 bytes of memory as if they are uint8_t, could you please specify the exact line where I do this? As far as I know I just declare a variable to be a 16 bit long integer and never change that.

Comment: In this line:   driver.send((uint8_t *)&package, sizeof(package));

Comment: I can’t believe I missed that, not sure what happens for the sensors that work fine.. at the receiving end the 6 int8’s are interpreted as 3 int16’s again

Comment: It works when I do not use a heavy DallasTemperature library but directly use OneWire as seen here: http://www.nerdkits.com/forum/thread/2849/, so I think it was indeed the memory issue @Jot mentioned..